# Overriding system style appearance in css does not work asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, dom

I am trying to make a css that can change `dropdown` control appearance as `label` and at same time some other `dropdown` in same page will appear with its default appearance, but the css class name will be same for both the `dropdown`, to achieve this I use *custom attribute* with control and same I used in css. Following is a sample code.

Here I have two `dropdown`, I need first one to be displayed as label and second one be editable.

I have added *custom attribute* on second `dropdown` to make it editable and same attribute I used in css, but the `dropdown` down-arrow key does not appear even I have overwritten it with its default appearance.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server" title="test">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .DropdownList, .DropdownListRequired {
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5;
            font-family: Calibri,"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
            border: none;
            transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
            color: #1E2935;
            line-height: 1;
            font-size: 13.5px;
            background-color: transparent;
            pointer-events: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            tab-index: -1;
            cursor: default;
            opacity: 0.55 !important;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: button-arrow-down;
            border: none;
        }
        .DropdownList[view=readonly-edit] {
            -webkit-appearance: default-button;
            -moz-appearance: button-arrow-down;
            padding: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
            border: 3px solid #2111f3;
            color: #ff0000;
            line-height: 1.4285;
            pointer-events: auto;
            -ms-user-select: auto;
            cursor: auto;
            background-color: white;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }               
    </style>
    <script lang="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearchApplicationStatus" CssClass="DropdownList" runat="server" Width="170px">
                <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Test2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Test3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Test4</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="DropdownList" runat="server" Width="170px" view="readonly-edit">
                <asp:ListItem>Opt1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Opt2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Opt3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Opt4</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Expire Cookie" OnClientClick="return ExpireCookie();" />--%>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

the second `dropdown` appears like this, I need it to appear with its default appearance with down-arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, the `-webkit-appearance:default-button` should be `-webkit-appearance:menulist`.

```
.DropdownList[view=readonly-edit] {
            -webkit-appearance: menulist;
            -moz-appearance: menulist;
            padding: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
            border: 3px solid #2111f3;
            color: #ff0000;
            line-height: 1.4285;
            pointer-events: auto;
            -ms-user-select: auto;
            cursor: auto;
            background-color: white;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
```